# In setTimeout, function is reading older version of global variable

Tags: javascript, delayed-execution

In a program I am working on, data is returned after many runs of a program. This program has a graphic output, so there is a specific frame rate that everything is running at. Here is the code:

```
function runTest(fps, testsPerRun, runs) {
    var main = setInterval(function(){
        runSetup(); //Set everything up for running the program once
        createGraphicOutput(); //Set up and clear the graphic output
        var code = setInterval(function(){
            runtest(); //Run one test
            updateCanvas(); //Update graphic output
        }, 1000 / fps);
        setTimeout(function(){
            clearInterval(code);
        }, turns * (1000 / fps));
    }, (1000 / fps) * testsPerRun);
    setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(main);
        interpretData(testsPerRun);
    }, ((1000 / fps) * testsPerRun) * runs);
}
```

When it is run, the `interpretData` function, which is supposed to `console.log` all of the data it stores is returning 0 for all. All of the data is in an array of objects, which has property "record" set to 0 at the beginning of the execution. During execution, I have confirmed that "record" does indeed change, but it thinks it's still 0. Why is this?

Comment: We can't tell without you showing us the code under test that handles the array.

Comment: This `setInterval` getting cleared from a `setTimeout` is really confusing. Better make a simple counter, and clear it when everything is done. Also a `setInterval` nested inside another `setInterval` is pretty sketchy. Better take a finish-callback-based approach and ensure that everything runs in the sequence you expect.